# How to Get the filtered data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, filter

I am having a database namely:  **ecom**.
Now in this database, I am having 3 collections: - 
**1. users

2. products

3. users_orders**

The Schemas of the tables are in the images: -

**Products: I have _id, productname, price

users_orders: I have _id, userId, prodId, quantity**

**users: I have _id and name.**

Suppose My user is **X** 
Now I want data from the database such that I get all the products(example : my cart) from db of my user and calculating the total price of the product in the db.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Please don't add screenshots as well as try to add what you have tried so far